# Named keywords in decorators?

Tags: python, decorator, keyword, named-parameters

I've been playing around in depth with attempting to write my own version of a memoizing decorator before I go looking at other people's code.  It's more of an exercise in fun, honestly.  However, in the course of playing around I've found I can't do something I want with decorators.

```
def addValue( func, val ):
    def add( x ):
        return func( x ) + val
    return add

@addValue( val=4 )
def computeSomething( x ):
    #function gets defined
```

If I want to do that I have to do this:

```
def addTwo( func ):
    return addValue( func, 2 )

@addTwo
def computeSomething( x ):
    #function gets defined
```

Why can't I use keyword arguments with decorators in this manner?  What am I doing wrong and can you show me how I should be doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a function that returns a decorator:

```
def addValue(val):
    def decorator(func):
        def add(x):
            return func(x) + val
        return add
    return decorator
```

When you write `@addTwo`, the value of `addTwo` is directly used as a decorator. However, when you write `@addValue(4)`, first `addValue(4)` is evaluated by calling the addValue function. Then the result is used as a decorator.

Comment: So you're saying that in Python decorators employ eager evaluation?  What a bummer.

Answer (score 5):

You want to *partially apply* the function `addValue` - give the `val` argument, but not `func`. There are generally two ways to do this:

The first one is called *currying* and used in interjay's answer: instead of a function with two arguments, `f(a,b) -> res`, you write a function of the first arg that returns another function that takes the 2nd arg `g(a) -> (h(b) -> res)`

The other way is a `functools.partial` object. It uses inspection on the function to figure out what arguments a function needs to run (*func* and *val* in your case ). You can add extra arguments when creating a partial and once you call the partial, it uses all the extra arguments given.

```
from functools import partial
@partial(addValue, val=2 ) # you can call this addTwo
def computeSomething( x ): 
    return x
```

Partials are usually a much simpler solution for this *partial application* problem, especially with more than one argument.

Comment: functools.partial, very nice.  I knew there was a simple way to get currying accomplished in Python without having to triple indent.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

Decorators with *any* kinds of arguments -- named/keyword ones, unnamed/positional ones, or some of each -- essentially, ones you **call** on the `@name` line rather than just **mention** there -- need a **double** level of nesting (while the decorators you just mention have a single level of nesting).  That goes even for argument-less ones if you want to **call** them in the `@` line -- here's the simplest, do-nothing, double-nested decorator:

```
def double():
  def middling():
    def inner(f):
      return f
    return inner
  return middling
```

You'd use this as

```
@double()
def whatever ...
```

note the parentheses (empty in this case since there are no arguments needed nor wanted): they mean you're *calling* `double`, which returns `middling`, which decorates `whatever`.

Once you've seen the difference between "calling" and "just mentioning", adding (e.g. optional) named args is not hard:

```
def doublet(foo=23):
  def middling():
    def inner(f):
      return f
    return inner
  return middling
```

usable either as:

```
@doublet()
def whatever ...
```

or as:

```
@doublet(foo=45)
def whatever ...
```

or equivalently as:

```
@doublet(45)
def whatever ...
```